# How can I force Turbo Assembler to use multiple passes when invoked from Turbo C?

Tags: programming

I'm using Turbo C and Turbo Assembler 2.01 to write a C wrapper around the XMS interface so I can use XMS memory in real mode, large model. I've started by writing the following:

```
#include <dos.h>

void (*xms_driver_interface)();

/*
   Query whether there is an XMS driver available.       
   Returns 1 if XMS memory is available.
*/
int xms_available()
{
   union REGS inregs, outregs;       
   inregs.x.ax = 0x4300u;       
   int86(0x2Fu, &inregs, &outregs);       
   return !!(outregs.h.al & 0x80u);
}

/*
   Query whether there is an XMS driver available,
   and populate xms_driver_interface if so.       
   Returns 1 if XMS memory is available and ready.
*/
int xms_init()
{
   union REGS inregs, outregs;
   struct SREGS sregs;
   int success;
   
   inregs.x.ax = 0x4310u;       
   int86x(0x2Fu, &inregs, &outregs, &sregs);       
   success = outregs.h.al;       
   if (!success) return 0;
   
   xms_driver_interface = (void (*)())((((unsigned long int)sregs.es) << 4) + ((unsigned long int)outregs.x.bx));   

   return 1;
}

unsigned int xms_get_version_number()
{
   _AX = 0x0000;
   
   asm call [xms_driver_interface]
   
   return _AX;
}
```

When Turbo C reaches the line `asm call [xms_driver_interface]`, it backs up and says it's `Restarting compile using assembly`, and switches to a two stage process where TCC compiles xms.c and TASM assembles it. TASM aborts with the error `xms.ASM(111) Forward reference needs override`, which seems like the output of the Turbo tools aren't mutually compatible because the generated xms.ASM is referring to `_xms_driver_interface` before declaring it, requiring two passes.

**Is there a way I can tell Turbo Assembler through Turbo C to use multiple passes on assembling?**

I know I can pass `/m2` to TASM directly, but when I split up my compilation process into separate phases it doesn't link correctly and it turns into a big mess.

Or is there some other method I should use to invoke my calculated pointer?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Or is there some other method I should use to invoke my calculated pointer?

See [Borland’s note on the subject](https://www.pcorner.com/list/CPP/TI1299.ZIP/TI1299.ASC/): if you declare your function pointer as

```
void far (*xms_driver_interface) (void);
```

you can call it directly:

```
(*xms_driver_interface)();
```

The note also shows how to construct the pointer in idiomatic Turbo C:

```
xms_driver_interface = (void (far *)(void)) MK_FP(sregs.es, outregs.x.bx);
```

or better yet,

```
_AX = 0x4310;
geninterrupt(0x2F);
xms_driver_interface = (void (far *)(void)) MK_FP(_ES,_BX);
```

An other possible approach, which is recommended in general when accessing C symbols from inline assembly (see chapter 7 of the Turbo Assembler 2.0 user’s guide), is to specify the symbol size (which is what the assembler needs to know, and determines using two passes otherwise):

```
asm call dword ptr xms_driver_interface
```

If you want to stick with inline assembly, you should add a `#pragma inline` at the start of your C file; this will restart `TCC` straight away in “compile using assembly” mode.

Comment: The segment shift of 4 is not correct. A far pointer has segment:offset pair, each is a 16-bit word.

Comment: Accepting this as the Users Guide is clear on this specific subject, but only if you're familiar with the terminology and know what you're looking for (which I'm not :) ): "However, it may be necessary to include appropriate WORD PTR, BYTE PTR, or other size overrides on assembly instruction. A DWORD PTR override is needed on LES or indirect far call instructions." page 280. This is the override the error message I quoted mentions.

Comment: Yes, I used to be intimately familiar with this, so reading the manual brings things back quickly ;-). When working with assembly and C in the Turbo environments, it’s important to realise that the integration on the C side is really basic, and the compiler won’t do much at all to help you. Things got better at some point in Borland C++, but I’m not sure when (3 or 4).

Comment: An additional tidbit, `#pragma inline` is equivalent to the `tcc -B` option if you happen to be compiling on the command line or via a MAKEFILE.

Answer (score 3):

One method that works around this for now is to write a shim .exe whose role is to call `system()` on `tasm.exe` with the `/m2` parameter added at the start of the list and use this as the assembler with `-Eshim.exe`. A batch file doing the same doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

> Or is there some other method I should use to invoke my calculated pointer?

Yes. Specify that it is a 32-bit (far) pointer:

```
asm call DWORD PTR [xms_driver_interface]
```